# Удалить повторяющиеся записи из таблицы

Tags: oracle, sql

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста. В моей таблице есть записи, которых порядка 8 штук. Как мне удалить 7 из них и оставить по 1?

Comment: Наверное, проще всего перенести (через SELECT DISTINCT) данные во временную таблицу, удалить старое содержимое, а потом загрузить из временной таблицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найти двойники по полю col1:

```
select col1, count(*)
from table1
group by col1
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: И что с ними дальше делать?

Answer (score 1):

Есть разные [способы](http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select17.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE rowid NOT IN (
SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM t
GROUP BY c)
```